# Ant http doesn't fail target

Tags: ant

I've been trying to get this to work all afternoon and can't.  I want to verify that my app is up and running from my ant script.  It seems that the below task should do the job but it doesn't.  I've gone through the ant documentation with a fine tooth comb trying various permutations but the documentation is very scant in terms of catching a failure from http.  Can anyone help.  Has anyone else got http working with ant ok?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="hermes" default="test-app-running" xmlns:epam="epam://epam.com" xmlns:catalina="antlib://catalina.apache.org" xmlns:artifact="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant">
    <target name="test-app-running" >       
        <waitfor maxwait="10" maxwaitunit="second">
            <http url="http://localhost:8080/" />
        </waitfor>
        <fail message="App did not come up.  Check your log files, fix and try again.  Good Luck :-).">     
            <condition>
                <http url="http://localhost:8080/" />
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: <target name="test-app-running" >  
  <waitfor maxwait="10" maxwaitunit="second">
   <http url="http://localhost:8080/" />
  </waitfor>
  <fail message="App did not come up.  Check your log files, fix and try again.  Good Luck :-).">  
   <condition>
    <http url="http://localhost:8080/" />
   </condition>
  </fail>
 </target>

Comment: what exactly is not working? Can you give some output, errors etc?

Comment: I want to be able to get the result from the http condition and fail the build if its negative.  The ant docs say that "....server errors, not-authorized, not-found and the like are detected".  The trouble here is how are they detected?  All I get when I run this target is .... test-app-running:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL . It reports success even when the url is non existent.

Comment: Its not a task its a condition.  Its in the current distribution of ant.  The docs are here [ant conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition needs a `<not />`. I just tested it and it works.

```
<fail message="App did not come up.  Check your log files, fix and try again.  Good Luck :-).">     
    <condition>
      <not>
        <http url="http://localhost:8080/" />
      </not>
    </condition>
 </fail>
```

Without the not it will fail if the server is up.

Comment: That sorted it out.  Thanks very much for your time.  I really appreciate the help you've given me here.